# Can't set a cookie from another controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to make a Stats stuff for a CakePhp site and for some reason I need to set a Cookie so I can trace the user

Then, in my StatsController I create a simple function with a $this->Cookie->write in it and made an actionRequest from my main Layout. The cookie is not there

Also, I tried to call that function from AppController with the same result, no cookie

Last thing is to create an element so I put it in main layout and tried the requestAction inside the element

Three ways and the cookie is not there

If I set the cookie with setcookie, then it works

I already load the Cookie component btw

Somewhere I read that you can't create/read cookies using another Controller than the one you call in first place because Controllers are intent to pass values only

I tried as regular Controller, also as Component and the same result

Comment: `requestAction` has been deprecated, you would be best off looking for an alternate structure for this functionality rather than trying to force it through cookies. From what you've written, cookies really seem like the wrong solution here anyway. How about `Configure::write` instead?

Comment: The cookie is to trace user across the site. As far I know Configure::write is for setting stuff on the site. Maybe I'm understanding wrong. Can't use sessions because they loses when user close the browser

Comment: So, you need data that persists across page loads, but you also need it to work right away when you set it and then call `requestAction`? That's not all clear from your post. If that's the case, I think the more typical solution would be to save the data in a session, and save the session key in a cookie.

Comment: So, the problem is that I can create cookies with $this->Cookie only inside AppController, but can't if I call another controller. That's why I think on requestAction (to call my Stats controller). It doesn't matter to me if is a pure Controller, or a Component or a plugin. Don't want to hardcode my Stats controller in AppController. Some inheritance, extend or something will do the work I guess

Comment: I suspect that the "problem" is that `requestAction` is handled internally rather than by generating a whole new request to the server (for example, you won't see the requested action showing up in your web server logs), and so any new cookie that you have written is not actually included in the request object that's passed to your Stats controller.

Comment: It seems likely that my "session plus cookie" suggestion above would resolve this, but it's also entirely possible that having a Stats "controller" is completely the wrong solution; if it has only a single action that's called for every request to any other controller, then handling that directly in the `beforeFilter` (or similar) of your AppController is probably the way to go.